# boostrap fileupload with phalcon

Tags: file-upload, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have  sequentially chosen five pictures,but the sort was chaotic.
For example,I choose 1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg,4.jpg,5.jpg,but show me 5.jpg,3.jpg,2.jpg,4.jpg,1,jpg.
Why?Thanks in advance.

Comment: file uploaded asychrously, it showed by finish sequence

Comment: How can I get the result sequentially? Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your show sequence refer to. image before upload or after.    make a jsfiddle may be more clear

Comment: 我顺序的选择5张图片12345，上传完之后论坛中显示的顺序变成了42315（随机的）

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set your upload mode to Synchronous.

```
$("#input-id").fileinput({'uploadAsync':false});
```

refer to [manual](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input#ajax-sync) and [bug](https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput/issues/420)